# Linq query for prioirty based email messages

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a email message table which will have email messages and then recipient table will have recipients of that email messages

EmailMessage

Id

Content

Priority

MessageRecipient

EmailMessageFk

RecipientEmailId

LastError

LastTriedAt

NextTryAt

Each message can have 1 to 10 priority where 1 is the lowest and 10 is the highest. I have created a function in C# which will try to resend all the pending email messages after certain interval.

I want to write a single linq query that can run on DB and will return most eligible record according to following criteria

a) If any of the message recipient has been last tried to be sent 12 hours before then it should that email message

b) if there is no recipient is found according (a) criterion then it should return the email message with the highest priority and if there are multiple email messages with the highest priority then it should return the message which has the highest priority and the lowest LastTriedAt date time.

Please remember, i want only one linq query to fulfill all these requirements

I was using following Query

```
 entities.EmailMessageRecipients.Where(
                            p => p.NextAttemptAt <= DateTime.UtcNow)
                            .Select(p => p.Message)
                            .Distinct()
                            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Priority)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Id)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

but this query has a flaw. if a lot of high priority messages got stuck in table then it will not try the previous low priority messages.

Comment: You will not only need to filter (Where) on NextAttemptAt but also sort (OrderBy) on NextAttemptAt.

Comment: but i cannot filter on nextattemptat because i need either a message with nextattemptat > 12 hours and if no such message exist then get a pending message with highest prioity

Comment: "Please remember, i want only one linq query to fulfill all these requirements".  What you want and what is appropriate are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve an `EmailMessage` entity then you should be querying `EmailMessages` rather than `EmailMessageRecipients`.  If you want the recipients as well then you can call `Include`.  As for the query, if I'm interpreting your conditions correctly then your first query should be something like this:

```
entities.EmailMessages.Where(em => em.EmailMessageRecipients.Any(emr => emr.NextAttemptAt <= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-12))
                      .OrderBy(em => em.LastTriedAt)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
```

That will get a message with at least one recipient whose `NextAttemptAt` is at least 12 hours ago if there is one.  If there are multiple matches then it will get the one with the oldest `LastTriedAt` value.  If that returns `null` then you can query by `Priority`.

Comment: but as i said in the question if a message with nextattemptat > 12 hours not found then get a pending message with highest prioity. this scenario is not covered

Comment: Yes, and as I said in the answer, if the query I provided returns `null` then you would make a second query by `Priority`. The fact that you think a single query is a good idea doesn't mean that it is.